# Can you route multiple GA4 accounts through one GTM Server Side Container?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-tag-manager-server-side

I have 2 websites at 2 different domains.

Each website has its own client side GTM container and each has its own GA4 account. However, a lot of the other marketing pixels such as Google Ads are the same across sites.

I'd rather not have a separate server side GTM Container if I can route the 2 GA4 accounts through the existing server side container. I'd rather have the economy of scale of 1 server.

Is it as simple as using separate server side GA4 tags where you'd enter the separate  GA4 measurement IDs and this in effect routes the traffic to the separate GA4 endpoint?

Thanks.